# Time for pushPayload? Saving records to ember-data

Tags: ember.js, websocket, ember-data

*Edited as I narrowed down issues....*

I'm working on an app that is taking in an API - data as JSON. It is an array of groups, with "name", "id", and other such elements.

```
{
 "status": "success",
  "data": {
  "groups": [
  {
    "id": 7100,
    "name": "Test 12345",
    "kind": "floor",
    "parent_group_id": 7000,
    "controlled_device_type_count": {},
    "is_top_level": true
  }
]
}}
```

I also have a livestream websocket - data as JSON stream. It should update the elements referenced in the first API. The two only share "id".

Livestream:

```
{
"group":{
"usage":{
    "10":1,
    "20":0,
    "30":2,
    "40":2
},
"last_change":"2014-03-24T05:56:10Z",
"id":7954
}}
```

**Updated...**My IndexRoute:

```
    App.ApplicationAdapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
  extractArray: function(store, type, payload, id, requestType) {
    payload = payload.data;
    return this._super(store, type, payload, id, requestType);
  }
});

App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
sortProperties: ['id'],
sortAscending: true,
beforeModel: function() {                
var socket = window.io.connect('http://localhost:8887');                                                           
var self = this;                                                                                                   
socket.on('group_live_stream', function(data){                                                                               
  var dataObj = JSON.parse(data);
  self.store.push('group',dataObj.group); 

});     

  },

    actions: {
toggleMenu: function() {
        this.controller.toggleProperty('menuVisible');
        this.controller.pushBody();
    }        },
activate: function() {
var self = this;
$.getJSON('http://localhost:3000/api/groups/top?subscribe=true').then(function(data) {

             self.store.pushMany('group', data.data.groups);

       });     

     },

model: function() {

 return this.store.all('group');


}
});
```

*Updated:*

So now I see the livestream coming through - and for a brief, immediate second - I see the API data (group name) and then it disappears. I'm thinking it's because I'm just "pushMany"-ing records and deleting old ones instead of updating. I've heard/read that pushPayload might be my solution....but I can't figure it out. At all (and when I put it in, I just get an error: "Uncaught Error: No model was found for '0' " Help?!

Any thoughts?

Thanks so much!

ptep

Answer (score 0):

Your API's payload is not in the format that ember-data expects (it looks for your payload in the root of your JSON by default). You'll need to override `extractArray` (and likely `extractSingle`) on your `ApplicationAdapter` something like this:

```
ApplicationAdapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
  extractArray: function(store, type, payload, id, requestType) {
    payload = payload.data;
    return this._super(store, type, payload, id, requestType);
  }
});
```

Comment: No dice, although I did update the route a bit. Thoughts on my disappearing data problem? Thanks, man!

Comment: The `Uncaught Error: No model was found for '0'` error would indicate that the JSON you're trying to push in is in an incorrect format - there's a key in the payload named `0` when it should be something like `group` or `groups`.

Comment: Excuse the possibly "dumb" question... (how) can I just tell it to use `group`?

Comment: You should do something like `store.pushPayload('{ group: { ... } }')` or `store.pushPayload('{ groups: [{}, {}, {}] }')` instead of `store.pushPayload('{ 0: { ... } }')` or `store.pushPayload('{ 0: [{}, {}, {}] }')`. Just check your JSON to make sure all's in order. :)